# vb.net ms access mdb table insert record code not works

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to insert data into MS Access database (mdb) table. The code is shown below:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Imports System.Data


        Dim Cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & pth & "\database.mdb; User Id=; Password=;")
        MsgBox(RichTextBox1.SelectedText)

        SQL = "insert into approved ( word, approveds) VALUES ('" & RichTextBox1.SelectedText & "', " & "'YES')"
        MsgBox(SQL)

        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
        Con.Open()
        objCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
```

It shows following error message

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Can any one please help
Or any other procedure

Comment: So, you're told that you have a data type mismatch in your SQL code but you thought that providing any information about the data types in use would not be a good idea?  My guess (we shouldn't have to guess stuff that you already know) is that your `approveds` column is type `Yes/No` in Access.  That does NOT mean that it contains the test "YES" or "NO".  Such a column contains Boolean values, i.e. `True` or `False`, so that's what you need to insert.  Booleans are treated in SQL in pretty much the same way they are in VB.

Comment: Also, you really ought to learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code.  Also, use "|DataDirectory|" in your connection string to represent the folder containing the data file.

Comment: That has never been the correct way to create SQL for NET.  Spend more time with the documentation and you'll spend less fiddling with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small addition to @zack raiyan 's code. That is the Using block which will close and dispose your connection. This is important with connection objects because they use unmanaged code.

I am guessing that since your error is a data type mismatch that the problem might be with the approveds column. If this is a Yes/No column then it should be safe to use True for the value.

Check the data types of the 2 parameters in your database table and adjust the code appropriately.

```
Private Sub AddRecord(pth As String)
    Dim SQL = "insert into approved ( word, approveds) VALUES (@word, @approval)"
    Using Con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & pth & "\database.mdb; User Id=; Password=;")
        Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox1.SelectedText
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@approval", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = True
        Con.Open()
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me, but i have an other field named id with auto increment integer, it shows message to insert value for id field what should i put there....         Cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = null or 0 are not working

Comment: Don't add the id field to the column list. You would not insert a value for an auto-increment field. If my answer was helpful please accept as the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first.

What do you expect `" & "'YES'` to mean ? Correct me if i'm wrong but you want to pass `Yes` as the value ? Or maybe even `"Yes"`(with quotes) ?

If it's the first one, only `Yes` inside single quotes would be enough(`'Yes'`). For the second case, it would be `'\"Yes\"'`.

There are still too many issues with your code. You are using `&` operator to concatenate strings. Some might argue that there's no problem with using `&` but look at the code and tell me what's your first expression? Well, my first expression was :

> That looks ugly!

So, instead of concatenation, you could simply format the string. Of course the results are the same, yet string formatting would look cleaner and more professional. Here's a sample :

```
 Dim x as String = "My Name Is {0}."
 Dim MyName As String = String.Format(x, "Zack Raiyan")
```

Now comes `MsgBox(SQL)`. Well, i don't need a second guess for this, *you are using this line to see if your sql statement is as expected.* If that's the case, why not just put a breakpoint ?

Now, let's talk about your variable declarations. Why declare a variable without initializing it with any instance but later on, just after a few lines of code, initialize it when this could've been done in the first place ? Sample :

```
Dim x As New ObjectX
```

**Instead of**

```
Dim x As Object
.....
.....
x = New Object()
```

Finally, if you are getting to frustrated reading all these suggestions, let's talk about the main culprit here, **your sql statement**.

```
insert into approved ( word, approveds)
```

A space before and after the parenthesis may not make any difference but why use them at all? You may be new in programming but understand this:

> You would spend 20% of your time in writing code and 80% of your time in maintaining it.

So, always write clean, simple & reusable codes.

Moving on....

```
 VALUES ('" & RichTextBox1.SelectedText & "')
```

**Don't do this!** Instead pass parameters and then pass values to them. A quick example :

```
Dim sql = New SqlCommand("Insert Into TableX(Column1)Values(@Column1Val)", MySqlConnection)

sql.Parameters.Add("@Column1Val", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "XYZ"
```

There's a shorter way tho :

```
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1Val", "XYZ")
```

but only use it when you know that you are passing a value of the same data type as the column you are passing it to.

I explained as much i could. I hope you understand your mistakes and also hope that you don't fail to see how my answer addresses the exception you are getting. If you are still unclear, leave a comment and i would be happy to help.

Comment: Dim SQL = New SqlCommand("Insert Into approved(word, approveds)Values(@Column1Val, @Column2Val)", MySqlConnection)
it shows red underline below the syntax keyword <  MySqlConnection > with message Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30109 'MySqlConnection' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression. WindowsApplication1 F:\our programming work\spell checker\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 2597 Active
 and can u please put full code to insert record it will be helping me

Comment: @fahad, in your case, `MySqlConnection` would be `Con`.